# Как можно посчитать числовые значения у разных хешей, в которых есть одинаковые ключи?

Tags: ruby

привет, подскажите, пожалуйста.
есть массив с хэшами.

```
results = [
  {theme: "Mathematic",
   student: "Alexander",
   score: 3},

  {theme: "Mathematic",
   student: "Dmitriy",
   score: 4},

   {theme: "Mathematic",
   student: "Maria",
   score: 5},

   {theme: "Russian Lang",
   student: "Alexander",
   score: 6},

   {theme: "Russian Lang",
   student: "Maria",
   score: 7},
]
```

как "схлопнуть" хеши по ученику?

То есть нужно высчитать у каждого ученика сумму баллов по всем предметам, например, у Александра это будет 9.

Пример результата:

```
{student: "Alexander", score: 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, спасибо добрым людям из телеграмм-чата.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
results.each_with_object(h) do | student, num |
  h[student[:student]] += student[:score]
end
```

Comment: Не очень, правда, понятно, зачем именно `each_with_object`, если `h` всё равно есть снаружи. А `num` не используется, да и имени своему не соответствует.

Comment: @D-side, Затем, что такие кодеры в телеграм-чатах.